# Understanding the getbbox method of a Pillow font object?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to find the bounding box of a font using pillow but I'm unsure how to understand the results I'm getting.

I'm using version 9.3.0.

The documentation says:

```
Returns:

    (left, top, right, bottom) bounding box
```

This is what I've written:

```
from PIL import ImageFont

text = 'test'
font_name = '/System/Library/Fonts/HelveticaNeue.ttc'
font_size = 7

font = ImageFont.truetype(font_name, font_size)
print(font.getbbox(text))
```

My output is `(0, 2, 12, 8)`

I don't understand why the top value isn't 0 (I would have thought the origin would be 0, 0). I'm also surprised the bottom value isn't 7, which is the font size given.

In fact, looking at the source code it says it should return 0, 0 for the origin:

```
    def getbbox(self, text, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Returns bounding box (in pixels) of given text.

        .. versionadded:: 9.2.0

        :param text: Text to render.
        :param mode: Used by some graphics drivers to indicate what mode the
                     driver prefers; if empty, the renderer may return either
                     mode. Note that the mode is always a string, to simplify
                     C-level implementations.

        :return: ``(left, top, right, bottom)`` bounding box
        """
        width, height = self.font.getsize(text)
        return 0, 0, width, height
```

Can anyone help me understand?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for being top value not equal to 0 is **stroke_width** (The width of the text stroke).

When **font** is initialized using the code mentioned, an object of **PIL.ImageFont.FreeTypeFont** is created.

```
font = ImageFont.truetype(font_name, font_size)
```

You are referring to the implementation of **getbbox** that belongs to a different class and not to **FreeTypeFont**. You can refer to the below implementation ([source code](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/9.2.0/src/PIL/ImageFont.py#L356-L418)):

```
    def getbbox(
    self,
    text,
    mode="",
    direction=None,
    features=None,
    language=None,
    stroke_width=0,
    anchor=None,
):
    """
    Returns bounding box (in pixels) of given text relative to given anchor
    when rendered in font with provided direction, features, and language.

    Use :py:meth:`getlength()` to get the offset of following text with
    1/64 pixel precision. The bounding box includes extra margins for
    some fonts, e.g. italics or accents.

    .. versionadded:: 8.0.0

    :param text: Text to render.
    :param mode: Used by some graphics drivers to indicate what mode the
                 driver prefers; if empty, the renderer may return either
                 mode. Note that the mode is always a string, to simplify
                 C-level implementations.

    :param direction: Direction of the text. It can be 'rtl' (right to
                      left), 'ltr' (left to right) or 'ttb' (top to bottom).
                      Requires libraqm.

    :param features: A list of OpenType font features to be used during text
                     layout. This is usually used to turn on optional
                     font features that are not enabled by default,
                     for example 'dlig' or 'ss01', but can be also
                     used to turn off default font features for
                     example '-liga' to disable ligatures or '-kern'
                     to disable kerning.  To get all supported
                     features, see
                     https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/featurelist
                     Requires libraqm.

    :param language: Language of the text. Different languages may use
                     different glyph shapes or ligatures. This parameter tells
                     the font which language the text is in, and to apply the
                     correct substitutions as appropriate, if available.
                     It should be a `BCP 47 language code
                     <https://www.w3.org/International/articles/language-tags/>`_
                     Requires libraqm.

    :param stroke_width: The width of the text stroke.

    :param anchor:  The text anchor alignment. Determines the relative location of
                    the anchor to the text. The default alignment is top left.
                    See :ref:`text-anchors` for valid values.

    :return: ``(left, top, right, bottom)`` bounding box
    """
    size, offset = self.font.getsize(
        text, mode, direction, features, language, anchor
    )
    left, top = offset[0] - stroke_width, offset[1] - stroke_width
    width, height = size[0] + 2 * stroke_width, size[1] + 2 * stroke_width
    return left, top, left + width, top + height
```